# Change shinyWidget's switchInput default colors in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, bootstrap-switch, shinywidgets

How to change color for SwitchInput elements (from ShinyWidgets package)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, in your `switchInput()` function, you must specify an "on" and "off" status by changing the `onStatus` and `offStatus` arguments:

```
switchInput(
                       inputId = "switch",
                       label = "Label", 
                       labelWidth = "120px", 
                       onLabel = "ON",
                       offLabel = "OFF",
                       onStatus = "danger",
                       offStatus = "info"
                     ),
```

Then, in your UI.r file or UI section of your Shiny app, add the following CSS tags:

```
#switchInput color while on
            tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-off.bootstrap-switch-danger,
                                       .bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-on.bootstrap-switch-danger {
                                        background: green;
                                        color: white;
                                        }'))),
            
#switchInput color while off
            tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-off.bootstrap-switch-info,
                                       .bootstrap-switch .bootstrap-switch-handle-on.bootstrap-switch-info {
                                        background: red;
                                        color: black;
                                        }'))),
```

Use `background` to set the background color of the switch, and `color` to set the text color.

Comment: Does this code also change the 'info' and 'danger' colors for other objects, or only for the switch?

Comment: @Jamie only for the switch, as the color change is done by matching the switch’s CSS classes